# How to move the Gimp plugins folder to the D drive

Tags: plugins, gimp

How do I move the Gimp plugins folder to my D drive?  I don't have room on my C drive for all of the plugins that I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the folder locations for plug-ins - and other resources like patterns, palettes, brushes - in GIMP's preferences. Expand the Folders entry at the end of the preferences list, and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NTFS junctions to move files within a folder to another drive. Normally you would need to pop open a command prompt to do this, but there is a tool called SteamMover which does all the commands for you. This tool was originally intended for moving Steam games, but it works as a general purpose NTFS junction tool as well. You can retrieve it at: http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover

After you download and open it, navigate to just one level above the plugins folder on the source drive, then choose a destination directory on your alternate drive. Click on the plugins folder, then click the right arrow to move it. You'll see a command prompt window opening up and doing things - this is normal, as the program is doing all necessary commands for you. Don't interrupt it, even if it takes a little bit depending on how big of a plugin collection you have. Once it disappears, your plugins folder will be on your alternate drive. GIMP can still access them as if nothing happened.